# Visual Studio extension menu button event not fireing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, event-handling, vsix

I have a project which has recently been converted from studio 2008 to 2010. It makes significant use of DSL. I used the DslProjectsMigrationTool that comes with the SDK. While much of the functionality is working I have a few problems with menus. I have a custom toolbar with three buttons which my code. However the event handler doesn't seem to be working. I've one back and checked the 2008 version and this was working without a problem.

Unfortunately none of this code is my own and the person who originally wrote it has moved on and is unavailable to help.

In Commands.vsct I have

```
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Commands package="guidPkg">
        <Menus>
            <Menu guid="guidCmdSet" id="blueprintToolbar" priority="0x0000" type="Toolbar">
                <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="blueprintToolbar"/>
                <CommandFlag>DefaultDocked</CommandFlag>
                <CommandFlag>AlwaysCreate</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>Blueprint Toolbar</ButtonText>
                </Strings>
            </Menu>         
        </Menus>

        <Groups>
            <Group guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpidTranslate" priority="0x0000">
                <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="blueprintToolbar" />
            </Group>
        </Groups>

        <Buttons>
            <Button guid="guidCmdSet" id="cmdidReTranslateAllCmd" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpidTranslate" />
                <Icon guid="guidCmdSet" id="bmpPic1"/>
                <CommandFlag>TextOnly</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>&lt;Retranslate All&gt;</ButtonText>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
            <Button guid="guidCmdSet" id="cmdidTranslateAllCmd" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpidTranslate" />
                <Icon guid="guidCmdSet" id="bmpPic1"/>
                <CommandFlag>TextOnly</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>&lt;Translate All&gt;</ButtonText>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
            <Button guid="guidCmdSet" id="cmdidTranslateCurCmd" priority="0x0102" type="Button">
                <Parent guid="guidCmdSet" id="grpidTranslate" />
                <Icon guid="guidCmdSet" id="bmpPic1"/>
                <CommandFlag>TextOnly</CommandFlag>
                <Strings>
                    <ButtonText>&lt;Translate Current&gt;</ButtonText>
                </Strings>
            </Button>
        </Buttons>

    </Commands>

    <Symbols>
        <GuidSymbol name="guidCmdSet" value="Extern">

            <!--Group IDs-->
            <IDSymbol name="grpidTranslate" value="0x1050"/>

            <!--Command IDs-->
            <IDSymbol name="cmdidTranslateAllCmd" value="0x9100"/>
            <IDSymbol name="cmdidTranslateCurCmd" value="0x9101"/>
            <IDSymbol name="cmdidReTranslateAllCmd" value="0x9102"/>

            <IDSymbol name="blueprintToolbar" value="0x1000"/>
            <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1"/>
        </GuidSymbol>

    </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Then in CommandSetOverride.cs I have

```
/// <summary>
/// Constants relating to commands
/// </summary>
partial class Constants
{
  public const string CLSID_StandardCommandSet97 = "5efc7975-14bc-11cf-9b2b-00aa00573819";

  #region Command Codes     

  const int cmdidTranslateAllCmd = 0x9100;
  const int cmdidTranslateCurrentCmd = 0x9101;
  const int cmdidReTranslateAllCmd = 0x9102;

  #endregion
  #region CommandIDs

  public static readonly CommandID TranslateAllCommandID = 
     new CommandID(new Guid(Constants.BlueprintCommandSetId), cmdidTranslateAllCmd);
  public static readonly CommandID TranslateCurrentCommandID =
     new CommandID(new Guid(Constants.BlueprintCommandSetId), cmdidTranslateCurrentCmd);
  public static readonly CommandID ReTranslateAllCommandID =
     new CommandID(new Guid(Constants.BlueprintCommandSetId), cmdidReTranslateAllCmd);

  #endregion 
}

/// <summary>
/// Additions to the blueprint command set for context menu items and extra commands.
/// </summary>
partial class BlueprintCommandSet
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Retrieves the available menu commands
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>List of menu commands</returns>
  protected override IList<MenuCommand> GetMenuCommands()
  {
     IList<MenuCommand> commands = base.GetMenuCommands();

     OleMenuCommand oleMenuCommand;

     // Translate
     if (null != MenuService)
     {
        MenuCommand menuCommand = new MenuCommand(new EventHandler(OnTranslateAll), Constants.TranslateAllCommandID);
        MenuService.AddCommand(menuCommand);

        menuCommand = new MenuCommand(new EventHandler(OnTranslateCurrent), Constants.TranslateCurrentCommandID);
        MenuService.AddCommand(menuCommand);

        menuCommand = new MenuCommand(new EventHandler(OnReTranslateAll), Constants.ReTranslateAllCommandID);
        MenuService.AddCommand(menuCommand);
     }

     return commands;
  }

  #region Translation 
  /// <summary>
  /// Handles the "ReTranslate All" toolbar button command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  private void OnReTranslateAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     ReTranslateAll();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Handles the "Translate All" toolbar button command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  private void OnTranslateAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     TranslateAll(false);
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Handles the "Translate Current" toolbar button command.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="sender"></param>
  /// <param name="e"></param>
  private void OnTranslateCurrent(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     TranslateCurrent();         
  }

  #endregion
}
```

When i run the code either the installed version or when running in the hive the buttons appear in the toolbar no problem however click on them never calls OntranslateAll or similar. Any help would be very useful.

Comment: I found that the CommandSetId Guid was used explicitly in two places and then one version was updated for the 2010 version while the second wasn't. With different guids the event was been sent to the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the CommandSetId Guid was used explicitly in two places and then one version was updated for the 2010 version while the second wasn't. With different guids the event was been sent to the wrong place